# What is the difference between an identifier and variable?

Tags: variables, identifier

I'm a bit confused about identifiers.  In my textbook it says, "We use identifiers to name variables (and many other things) in Java."

I'm not really sure what this means. Is it like assigning a variable...to a variable? What?

So far, I'm getting this impression:

```
int a, b, c; a = 2; b = 99; c = a + b;
```

Is `c` an identifier? When it says, "Using identifiers to name variables," are identifiers like `int`, `double`, `boolean`, things used to categorize variables?  Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 33):

You can think of an identifier as variable's name. I wouldn't get too worked up about it.

For example:

```
int a;
a = 15;
```

In this example, `a` is a identifier that refers to the variable with the same name. If `a` weren't a variable but a function:

```
int a()
{
}

a();
```

Then `a` would still be an identifier but it would identify a function. Just as "Reena" can identify both a person and [some kind of a non-profit organization.](http://www.reena.org/)

Comment: Good analogy between Reena as a person and Reena as organization

Comment: Very nice example.

Comment: an identifier is not just a variable's name, as you even show later in your answer, so your first sentence is misleading

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the GNU C's definition that says that there are 5 tokens in C: keywords, identifiers, operators, constants and separators. The same goes for Java.

`int` is not an identifier because it is defined as a keyword. Operators are excluded from the list of valid identifier symbols. Constants are just values, but the name that refers to a constant is an identifier.

Basically: any 'word' (a group of 1 or more valid identifier symbols) is an identifier as long as it isn't on the list of keywords. In Java, the valid identifier symbols are Unicode letters, digits, dollar and underscores. Digits *can't* be the first symbol. Dollars and underscores, though valid, *shouldn't* be used with the exception of as a separator in multi-word constant identifiers like `MY_MAGIC_NUMBER = 6`.

Answer (score 5):

An identifier is just the name of the variable. So for the variable `c`, the identifier is the actual text `c`, which is just your way of referring to the variable. It's possible (as you'll learn later on) that you can have multiple identifiers for the same variable, kinda like how in real life a person can have multiple names.

Don't worry too much about it right now, just keep trying and focusing on the more important stuff like loops, conditionals, classes, etc.

Comment: Multiple identifiers for the same variable? I've only seen that in C++. You can have multiple references to the same object, but an object is not a variable. Conversely, multiple variables with the same identifier are possible in every language with shadowing, namespaces, or even just scope.

Comment: identifiers are not just names of variables. you should give a definition of identifier

Answer (score 4):

Identifier are the names of variables and variables are storage locations of data.Variables point to the memory location where data is read and modified

Comment: identifiers can hold constants too, not just variables, so your definition is wrong even in your first sentence. And the name of a class is an identifier too

Answer (score 3):

In Java, identifier is the name given to a program element, where a program element could be a package, type (class, interface, enum, annotation), fields (instance/static *variables*), enum constants, annotation type elements, methods, local *variables*, and parameters. Essentially, an identifier identifies a program element.

For example, in the following code,

```
package declarations;

public class A {

    private int value = 1;

    private enum SUITS {CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE};

    public A(int val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public int doSomething() {
        int c = value + 10;
        return c;
    }
}

// declarations, A, value, SUITS, CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE,
// A, val, value, val, doSomething, c, value, c are the 
// identifiers in order of their occurrence.
```

Comment: your definition of identifier could be improved if you cited a source, also, you missed out constants. So if you had a source and included a complete definition for identifier in java then that'd be good

Answer (score 2):

Identifier is just like the name of any user define function such as

```
int gcd(int,int);
```

Here the name of function gcd is an identifier.

And variable is uses for assigining the value these may vary during the executaion, such as

```
int a,b;
int a=10;
```

In the above two expression first is declare the variable and second we assign the value 10.
Here a and b are variables.

Comment: Please use the code formating next time. I have edited your answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly this seems to be an example of over-engineering (in the context of over-thinking variable names (Identifiers))

// Variable definition

int myVariable = 42;

technically speaking

42 is the variable (assigned value).

myVariable is the Identifier (name we create to store the variable)

I typically work under the generic idea of referring to Identifiers as variables and if you wanted to get technical, make the distinction that the "name we create to store the variable is the 'variable name' and the value stored in the 'variable name' is the 'variable value'.

Comment: This question intrigued me because it is a simple concept but often confusing to beginners such as myself trying to get our heads around the larger concepts of Java programming.  So I did some digging and found what I think is a good definition of a Java Identifier (reference: Beginning Java 8 Fundamentals by Kishori Sharan).

To Summarize:
An Identifier is simply the technical term for a name given to a class, method, variable, file etc. in a java program.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a *variable* is a **defined storage region**; the fact there is a place in your RAM for you where you can save values. A *variable identifier* is the name you give to that region.

Of course, an identifier can name more than variables. A function (a pack of code with in/out parameters) also has a name: the *function identifier*. A type (value domain), also has a name, the *type identifier*. A class (type with function members), has the *class identifier*, and so on.

For example, '4' is a value. Even more, it's an integer. What if you want to manage your own integers? You need a storage region to save integers, a name to refer to that storage region, you need to define what kind of values (type/domain) you want to save in that region, and a name to refer and to specify that type. So, you write something like:

```
int var;
```

If the Java parser sees a sentence with the following structure: `name name;`, he knows you are creating a storage region. The first part specifies the type of values that region is intended for, and the only mean to specify it is writting the type identifier of that type, because the type itself is an abstract notion (for example, `int` for the abstract notion of something being an integer).

The second part is the name you want to give to that region, to use it later, because refering to a storage region using a name is simpler than using any other mean (for example, memory direction or whatever; left the language manage that for you).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to do this without giving an example.

Every piece of data in the program is stored somewhere in the computer's memory, and its address is given a name. The name used to refer to this memory location is called *identifier*.

If the data at this location can be changed at runtime this identifier is called a *variable*. If not, we say it is a *constant*.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers are the words that represent a variable or function, but the variable is the space within the ram to store the data. For example: once you declare a variable such as: `int god;` the word `god` is the identifier and `int god;` is the variable declared to enter an integer data.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. "int" is not an identifier - it is a variable type. An identifier in your example is the word "god", which is also a variable with the same name. "int god" is a declaration of a variable of type int.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words variable is something that occupy space in memory and identifier is the name to that location.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers are names given to things in Java. This includes variables, methods, classes, etc. So, technically a variable is an identifier. 
see: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/var-ident.html

Regarding your confusion on "I'm not really sure what this means. Is it like assigning a variable...to a variable? What?" --> the correct way of saying is: Assigning a "name" to variable (what name would you like for a variable).

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, the names of variables, functions, labels, and various other user-defined objects are called identifiers.
                      16th page, C++: The Complete Reference, Herbert Schildt.

Answer (score 0):

adding to above answers

every variable is an identifier but every identifier is not a variable.

ex1) name of a function is an identifier but not variable

Comment: Can you please explain further your solution ?

Comment: i meant, a function name is not a variable since we don't intend to store any value in it although a function's name itself will store the address of first statement of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Identifier is used to identify variables like your name identifies you but you are not your name, you are just identified by it. Identifier can also be used to identify functions as pointed out by the top rated answer of user267885. int is not an identifier but a keyword declaring the type of the variable.