# Can I call the parameter of a function an identifier?

Tags: c

Identifiers are names that are given to various program elements, such as variables, functions and arrays. We can write a function, 
for example:

```
int function (int x);
```

Here, the parameter of the function is `int x`.

My question is: can we call the parameter an identifier?

Comment: Are you asking if, given the example, `x` is considered an *identifier* ? [The answer is *yes*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439735/what-is-the-difference-between-an-identifier-and-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` identifies a parameter of your function, which can be used as a variable (identifier) in calculations. So yes, `x` is an identifier.

Answer (score 4):

From the [c standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.4.2 Identifiers**
>
> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the
> lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates
> one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct.
> There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

> **6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers**
>
> 1 An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or
> enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter. The
> same identifier can denote different entities at different points in the program. A member
> of an enumeration is called an enumeration constant. Macro names and macro
> parameters are not considered further here, because prior to the semantic phase of
> program translation any occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the
> preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions.
> [...]

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>